# AngularJS Unable to Use Controller or App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I do not understand why this is not working. I created a test output for AngularJS before the controller call and it works as expected but the same command does not work inside the controller. The out put is:

```
> Fun with Countries
> 
> {{ "Hello " + "World" + "!" }}

> {{ "Hello " + "World" + "!" }}
```

If I remove the app name then the to ng-app, then my output is:

```
> Fun with Countries
> 
> Hello World!   
> {{ "Hello " + "World" + "!" }}
```

I have not been able to solve this issue. Below is the code.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="funwithcountries">
        <h1>Fun with Countries</h1>
        {{ "Hello, World!" }}
        <div ng-controller="CountryController as countryCtrl">
            {{ "Hello " + "World" + "!" }}
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('funwithcountries', []);

    app.controller('CountryController', function() {

    });
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted to enclose your code in an IIFE, but you didn't let it call itself. Basically you forgot the `()`, try adding the '()' at the end:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('funwithcountries', []);

    app.controller('CountryController', function() {

    });
}());
```

This should invoke your anonymous function and define the `angular.module`.

Hope that helps